# importing packages using rjava

Tags: import, package, rjava

I am using rjava package and am calling a function from a class, but the class requires importing other classes.

Eg:

```
  test=J("com.abc.commons.entity.olap.viewer/OlapLayout")
  d <- new( test )
  d$addDimensionFilter("Promotion Name", "Promotion_Name", "STARTSWITHIGNORECASE", "s")
```

No its throwing an error because OlapLayout function needs to import other classes like:

```
com.abc.commons.entity.olap.common/cube
com.abc.commons.entity.olap.viewer/dimension
```

How could this be done? 
Thanks